# Use an apply function to a subset of rows in a data frame - vectorised solution

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I am trying to implement a vectorised solution that iterates through each row of a data frame during each iteration, sends a function two arguments.  These arguments correspond to columns in the data frame.

Here is some code which hopefully makes this question clearer.

```
fnATimesB <- function(a, b) {
  return(a * b)
 }

vct.names <- c("mark", "fred", "ben")
vct.days <- c(1, 3, 5)
vct.salary <- c(1000, 4000, 5000)
df.data <- data.frame(name = vct.names, days = vct.days, sal = vct.salary)

# want to use something like the following:

sapply(df.data, fnATimesB, days , sal)

# expected result
# 1000
# 12000
# 250000
```

Comment: Just use `fnATimesB(df.data$days,df.data$sal)`. If that doesn't work, it means that `fnATimesB` is not properly vectorized and you should rewrite it (if possible). Details of that function matter.

Comment: Can you use simply `vct.days * vct.salary` ?

Comment: I suspect there's a hidden point somewhere, in your function if there non vectorized functions ? (because here you can just do `fnATimesB(df.data['days'],df.data['sal'])`)

Comment: Probably your example is not totally reflecting your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Yeh..I see your point.  I am trying to use this example..I have posted as a vehicle to better understand the apply functions...my actual problem is a bit more complex.. I am iterating though a data frame and at each row, I am passing 3 arguments.  The function that receives this then returns the coordinates for a hexagon. This means that there are 6 x 2 = 12 values returned.

Comment: Maybe you still don't need `apply`, try to improve your question and we will see.

Comment: As I said before, details matter. Please, post your function, otherwise it will be difficult to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All other solutions assuming the function called is vectorized, here's another if it's not the case:

```
sapply( 1:nrow(df.data), function(x) { 
                              fnATimesB( df.data[x,'days'], df.data[x,'sal'] )
                           } )
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `apply` here and avoid the anonymous function call, while slightly modifying your original function instead. The only thing to remember is that `apply` converts the data set to a matrix and thus, you shouldn't have non-numeric columns in the input data, here is an example

```
fnATimesB <- function(df, a, b) {
  df[a] * df[b]
}

apply(df.data[-1L], 1L, fnATimesB, a = 'days', b = 'sal')
## [1]  1000 12000 25000
```

Comment: But really, review your function, it probably can be vectorized itself and avoid this kind of trick.

Comment: @markthekoala if you want to avoid the anonymous call, update your function (or make a wrapper function) to take only the row index as parameter.

Comment: @markthekoala see the edit for an option without an anonymous function.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - i've pondered this question before - my alternatives were: `do.call(mapply, c(fnATimesB,unname(df.data[-1])) )` or even `do.call(mapply, c(fnATimesB,setNames(df.data[-1],c("a","b"))) )` when using the original function.

Comment: @thelatemail interesting, I didn't really spend too much time thinking of it. You could probably at this as an edit too.

Answer (score 0):

simply write:

```
with(df.data, vct.days*vct.salary)
```

Comment: This will work. Thanks Shahab. But the actual function is much more complex than the multiplication of two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
with( df.data, fnATimesB(days,sal))
```

will give a vector